# DynamoDB Batch Write Item Limits

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am currently doing a batch load to DynamoDB and dividing our data items into batch units:

According to the limits documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Some of the limits are:

> There are more than 25 requests in the batch.
>
> Any individual item in a batch exceeds 400 KB.
>
> The total request size exceeds 16 MB.

The big unknown for me is how is possible with `25` items of a maximum of `400` Kb, the payload will exceed 16Mbs. Accounting for table names of less than 255 bytes, etc. I don't understand the limit or am I missing something simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The 16MB size is actually the total size of the request. Consider an object with many many small objects, the DynamoDB request map could be larger than the size of the combined items.

Answer (score 0):

The 16 MB limit applies to the JSON formatted data sent over the network, and the 400 KB limit applies per record in the database and will always be smaller than the size of the record in JSON format.

From the documentation you linked in your question:

> While individual items can be up to 400 KB once stored, it's important to note that an item's representation might be greater than 400KB while being sent in DynamoDB's JSON format for the API call.

In JSON format, a record can be greater than 400 KB, but the sum total of the records in JSON format cannot exceed 16 Mb.

Each record, after being decoded from JSON and stored in the database, cannot exceed 400KB.